# Firefox GCLI (internal command line) won't open

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m used to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open the [graphical command-line interpreter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI) in Firefox. This is useful for [taking screenshots of webpages](https://askubuntu.com/a/589702/652) and for restarting the browser when I’ve opened a ridiculous number of tabs. (I love the way Firefox doesn’t load tabs till you visit them: allows me to middle click and open 500 tabs, then restart the browser and visit them one at a time without running out of memory.)

Ever since the update to Firefox Quantum, however, the toolbar has become inconsistent. Sometimes it opens, and sometimes nothing happens.

At the moment, it still exists in the menu (Web Developer → Developer Toolbar) and is ticked, but I’m not seeing it. Unticking and reticking has no apparent effect. Nor does the keyboard shortcut.

The weird bit is that some days it works fine, and some days it just doesn’t exist. I’m running Firefox on Ubuntu.

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is actually <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>.

However, as your documentation link says in bright red, GCLI [was scheduled for removal](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/firefox-dev/2018-March/006249.html) (it is now gone in Firefox 62).

The screenshot feature will be added [as a *screenshot()* function](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1464461) to the Dev Tools JS console.

Comment: It's there now. The fact that it's going (a pity: I like it) doesn't explain why it's working inconsistently now. (And yes, the Ctrl was a typo.)